# how to read with supplyFile()?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, alchemy

**Short version:**

I see there is an alchemy method called supplyFile(), but the second arg is a ByteArray... what in the world is that for?!?!

**Longer version:**

I would like to do the following:

1. Open a file and assign it to a global variable on the C side of alchemy.
2. Read in (and process) a chunk of bytes on the C side
3. Send them to Actionscript for display
4. Go to step 2 until EOF or notification from Actionscript
5. Close the file

I'm able to do this right now by opening the file and reading the chunks into a ByteArray on the Actionscript side and then passing it to C for processing and back- but this calls some unnecessary overhead by needing to do AS3_ByteArray_writeBytes()/AS3_ByteArray_readBytes() on the C side in order to manipulate the data in a char *.

**Is there any way to simply fopen() a file on the C side and read in some bytes?**

Asssume we are talking about a very large file on disk (>4GB).

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy%3aDocumentation%3aDeveloping_with_Alchemy%3aAS3_API):

> *supplyFile(path:String, data:ByteArray):* This method allows you to
>   provide a file at a specified path for the C code. This is useful if
>   your C code expects a configuration file at a specific location that
>   is not accessible to the runtime due to security restrictions.

In other words, `supplyFile` lets you create a "virtual file" that can be accessed from C with `fopen`.

You call `supplyFile` with a string that represents the path to the virtual file (this can be anything you want it to be) and a ByteArray that is the contents of that virtual file.  Then, on the C side you call `fopen` with the virtual file path and use `fread` and friends just like an ordinary file.

Comment: Oh... so is there no way to fread a real file on disk on the C side?

Comment: Can you read a real file on disk with ActionScript?  As the alchemy C code is running within the Flash VM, you can't do anything with C that you can't already do with ActionScript.

Comment: Yes... I can read a file into a ByteArray, but C can't process a ByteArray directly. It needs to then read that ByteArray into a char *buffer. That means the usual C "read into buffer" is turned into a "read into bytearray then read that into buffer." The second read is probably much faster since its in memory, but since this is for something which will repeated often in a loop... there's got to be a better way which avoids two reads?

Comment: Are you using AIR?  Anyway, if you have the file in a ByteArray-- you can pass it into C via supplyFile, where C can then use fopen/fread to read it.

Comment: If you're using AIR, you can use funopen to bind fread and friends to AIR's file io stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4368865/89218

Comment: Thanks- but let me try explaining again: I've already had to do one read (in Actionscript) to get the data from the file into a ByteArray. Is another fread() or AS3_ByteArray_readBytes() *really* necessary just to work with the data on the C side?

Comment: You have to get the data into to Alchemy's virtual RAM somehow.  Another possibility is to copy it in directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891641/how-to-pass-bytearray-to-c-code-in-alchemy

Comment: Check the comments on the first link: "However iterating over a large array like this can be slow. painfully slow… So I returned to AS3_ByteArray_readBytes()" and the second link is closer to what I'm after in example #2, but it relies on Strings-only with StrType, it won't work with passing a ByteArray like that. Thanks though!

Comment: OK, I think there is a solution- the domain memory is actually seen as a ByteArray on the actionscript side. So it's maybe possible to FileStream.readBytes() directly into the domain memory space by allocating the pointer as a char * on the C side, passing that pointer to the actionscript side, and reading it directly into that pointer (an offset of AS3_Ram())

But with Alchemy2 coming out, I'm not going to check this out at the moment to make sure. Thanks!